# Include router-link in google maps infowindows - vuejs

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I am building an app in Laravel 5.7 with VueJS. I have a google map (built using vue2-google-maps) with 200+ markers, each with an infowindow. I would like to include a router-link within the infoWindow but it seems that as the link is passed as a string it is not being parsed by Vue.

This is my component at the moment - all working except the router-link

Can anyone suggest a way of getting vue to parse the router-link?

Thank you

```
<template>
<div id="map">

    <gmap-map
            :center="center"
            :zoom="11"
            style="width:100%;  height: 750px;"
            map-type-id="satellite"
    >

        <GmapMarker v-for="location in locations"
                    :key="location.id"
                    @click="toggleInfoWindow(location, location.id)"
                    :position="({
                        lat : location.latitude,
                        lng : location.longitude,
                        }
                    )"
        ></GmapMarker>
        <gmap-info-window
                :options="infoOptions"
                :position="infoWindowPos"
                :opened="infoWinOpen"
                @closeclick="infoWinOpen=false"
        >
            <div v-html="infoContent"></div>
        </gmap-info-window>

    </gmap-map>


</div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                center: {lat: 51.553726, lng: -0.110035},
                locations: [],
                visits:[],
                infoContent: '',
                infoWindowPos: {
                    lat: 0,
                    lng: 0
                },
                infoWinOpen: false,
                currentMidx: null,
                //optional: offset infowindow so it visually sits nicely on top of our marker
                infoOptions: {
                    pixelOffset: {
                        width: 0,
                        height: -35
                    }
                }
            }

        },

        methods: {
            getLocations(){

                window.axios.get('/api/locations').then(({data})=>{
                    data.forEach(location => {
                        this.locations.push(location)
                    });
                });
            },


            toggleInfoWindow: function (marker, idx) {

                this.infoWindowPos = ({
                        lat : marker.latitude,
                        lng : marker.longitude,
                    }
                );
                this.infoContent = this.getInfoWindowContent(marker);

                //check if its the same marker that was selected if yes toggle
                if (this.currentMidx == idx) {
                    this.infoWinOpen = !this.infoWinOpen;
                }
                //if different marker set infowindow to open and reset current marker index
                else {
                    this.infoWinOpen = true;
                    this.currentMidx = idx;
                }
            },

            getInfoWindowContent: function (marker) {
                return(`<div class="info_window container">
                          <h3>${marker.name}</h3>
                          <a href="/location/${marker.slug}"><div class="mx-auto btn btn-success">More Info</div></a>
                          <router-link :to="/location/${marker.slug}" class="mx-auto btn btn-success">RL More Info</router-link>
                         </div>`);
            },


        },

        created(){
            this.getLocations()

        },


    };
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow !  Please try to push small snippets of code that replicate your issue. It will be a easier for anyone to understand what you’re asking.  You may also want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get some pro tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-html` directive simply passes the data you pass to it directly into the DOM as `innerHtml` of that element. This is great if you want to pass something that is already html, but not so great if Vue needs to do something with that.

Instead you have to use the template itself. If it is in the component itself, like here, this is simple. Instead of generating some html string, instead put the entire thing inside your template and use moustache notation, `v-if`'s and the like to control what is shown where. If instead you have a separate component, you can use slots to control what is passed to your info window. You then pass content to that slot via the parent's template.

---

To fix your issue, you have to do something like this. First assign your marker to some variable we can use within the template. We can just re-use `infoContent` in this case.

```
    toggleInfoWindow: function (marker, idx) {
        this.infoWindowPos = ({
                lat : marker.latitude,
                lng : marker.longitude,
            }
        );
        this.infoContent = marker;

        //check if its the same marker that was selected if yes toggle
        if (this.currentMidx == idx) {
            this.infoWinOpen = !this.infoWinOpen;
        }
        //if different marker set infowindow to open and reset current marker index
        else {
            this.infoWinOpen = true;
            this.currentMidx = idx;
        }
    },
```

Now we modify the template to have your html and components inside `gmap-info-window`. Since we assigned our active marker to `infoContent`, we reference it here.

```
    <gmap-info-window
            :options="infoOptions"
            :position="infoWindowPos"
            :opened="infoWinOpen"
            @closeclick="infoWinOpen=false"
    >
        <div class="info_window container">
            <h3>{{ infoContent.name }}</h3>
            <a :href="`/location/${infoContent.slug}`"><div class="mx-auto btn btn-success">More Info</div></a>
            <router-link :to="`/location/${infoContent.slug}`" class="mx-auto btn btn-success">RL More Info</router-link>
        </div>
    </gmap-info-window>
```

Now, when you call `toggleInfoWindow`, the info window will now update with the new marker information.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation - it's working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

The `v-html` directive as used in the following extract from your code can't be used for composing template partials <sup>[[1]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)</sup>.

```
<div v-html="infoContent"></div>
```

In this use case, infoContent could benefit from being implemented as a separate component that can be registered in the following way <sup>[[2]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Component-Names)</sup>

```
<template>
<!--...-->
  <gmap-info-window
    :options="infoOptions"
    :position="infoWindowPos"
    :opened="infoWinOpen"
    @closeclick="infoWinOpen=false"
  >
    <info-content 
      v-bind:slug="marker.slug"
      v-bind:name="marker.name"
    >
    </info-content>
  </gmap-info-window>
<!--...-->
</template>

<script>
import InfoContent from './components/InfoContent.vue'

export default {
   components: {
     InfoContent
   },
   data() { /*...*/ },
   methods: { 
     //...
     toggleInfoWindow (marker, idx) {
       //...
       this.marker = marker;
       //...
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

**components/InfoContent.vue**

```
<template>
   <div class="info_window container">
    <h3>{{ name }}</h3>
    <a href="/location/{{ slug }}">
      <div class="mx-auto btn btn-success">More Info</div>
    </a>
    <router-link
      :to="/location/{{ slug }}"
      class="mx-auto btn btn-success">
      RL More Info
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'info-content',
  props: {
    slug: String,
    name: String
  }
}
</script>
```